# How to loop through an object and push into an array

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

**What I'm working with**

- angular2
- firebase

**What I have**

- A returned object
- Each item in the object has a URL property

**What I would like to do**

- Loop through each of the items in the object and get the URL property
- Pass that into a firebase storage variable
- Push the URL property into an array to make available for my HTML

**note:** I have this working by hard coding a url, I just need some assistance looping through the object to get the other urls in the object.

**Component.ts**

'this.imagesToDisplay' will return an object of object (image below)

```js
this.activatedRoute.data
  .subscribe((
    data: { issueData: any, issueImageData: any }) => {
    this.issueToDisplay = data.issueData;
    this.imagesToDisplay = data.issueImageData; 

    this.testing(this.imageToDisplayArray); 

  });
```

[image]

**Comnponent TS - Testing method**

So this is hardcoded and pushes the hardcoded url into the array and displays correctly through databinding with the HTML. Cool. However, I would like to loop through the 'imagesToDisplay' object and get both returned urls.

```js
  testing(imageToDisplayArray) {
    
    // this works with one url
    var storage = firebase.storage().ref().child("image/-Kosd82P-bmh4SFetuf3/-Kosd8HhGmFiUhYMrlvw/30DD9F39-4684-4AA0-9DBF-3B0F0C3450A4.jpg");
    storage.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    imageToDisplayArray.push(url);
        console.log(imageToDisplayArray);
    });

  }
```

Any help here would be massively appreciated.

**Note**: I think this question here is what I'm trying to do, I'm just not sure how to integrate that into my current code. Any help would be awesome.
[Stack Overflow question on firebase storage looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766447/how-can-i-display-an-image-from-firebase-storage-without-repeating-image-in-the?rq=1)

**UPDATE**

So, I'm incredibly close now. I just have one issue. The code below loops through the returned data and extract the URL properties. I use the url properties to connect to the firebase storage and return the download URLs. Both of these are logged to the console! Awesome. I now have the URLs i needed! The issue I'm having is, it will only let me push these values to a local array. In this instance 'var array'. I need to push to an array that's outside of the 'activatedRoute' 'method'. Anytime I do, it returns as undefined.

```js
this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((
        data: { issueData: any, issueImageData: any }) => {
        this.issueToDisplay = data.issueData;
        this.imagesToDisplay = data.issueImageData;

        var array = [];

        data.issueImageData.forEach(image => {

          // Reference to the image URL
          var image = image.url;

          // Firebase storage
          var storage = firebase.storage();

          // Path reference
          var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);

          // Get Download URL
          imagePathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            console.log(url);
            array.push(url);
          })
        });


      });
```

Comment: Could you add an example of `this.imagesToDisplay`? A fully working example would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And check this answer out for a general approach for iterating through an object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: Hey @sventies. I'm not entirely sure how to present a working example of my angular solution outside of my environment unfortunately. There are quite a few connected files and dependencies at the moment. "this.imagesToDisplay" returns the data seen in the sreenshot. In this instance it's an object of object which contain the urls I need to loop through and push into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this works. Not entirely sure how clean it is. But it works.

```js
 this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((
        data: { issueData: any, issueImageData: any }) => {
        this.issueToDisplay = data.issueData;
        this.imagesToDisplay = data.issueImageData;

        var localImageArray = [];

        data.issueImageData.forEach(image => {

          // Reference to the image URL
          var image = image.url;

          // Firebase storage
          var storage = firebase.storage();

          // Path reference
          var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);

          // Get Download URL
          imagePathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
            localImageArray.push(url);
          })

            this.getIssueImageArray(localImageArray);
        });


      });
  }

  // Get Image Array
  getIssueImageArray(array) {
    this.imageToDisplayArray = array;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the features `rxjs` provides you:

```
this.activatedRoute.data.switchMap(data => {
    let parsedData = { 
        issueToDisplay: data.issueData,
        imagesToDisplay: data.issueImageData
    }
    let imageUrls$ = data.issueImageData.map(image => {
        var imagePathReference = storage.ref().child(image);
        return Observable.fromPromise(imagePathReference.getDownloadURL())
    });
    return Observable.forkJoin(imageUrls$).map((...urls) => {
        return Object.assign(parsedData, { urls });
    })
}).subscribe(data => {
    /* 
    data looks like this:
    {
        issueToDisplay: any,
        imagesToDisplay: any,
        urls: string[]
    }
    */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you're looking for a solution to map an array-like object of objects to an actual array of objects.

Here is a way to do just that:

```js
var object = {
  '0': {
    "url": "url1",
    "name": "obj1",
    "data": 1234
   },
  '1': {
    "url": "url2",
    "name": "obj2",
    "data": 5678
   },
   'length': 2
}

var sliced = Array.prototype.slice.call( object, 0 );

console.log(sliced)
```

**Couple remarks:**

- If you wonder how this works, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work).
- Alternative syntax that you could encounter looks like `[].slice.call()`
- If you want to perform array-like operations, you can probably do that right away with `Array.prototype.<METHOD>.call(object, <CALLBACK>`
- For example:

`Array.prototype.map.call(object, function(el) { // return your enhanced element })`

Comment: In short, I simply want the two urls (in this instance. It could 40) from that object and have them in an array that I can loop through.

Comment: It then means that once I have that array, I could probably do something like: var storage = firebase.storage().ref().child(). In the child it'll be each url from the array. That's the aim at least.